# How to get or seperate drawing objects from a bitmap in javascript, Objects like lines, ovals etc

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a picture with ovals, rectangles, lines , splines, polygons etc.
i want all that shapes or arbitrary objects as a separate bitmaps.

what i have tried is that: i am scanning picture - all the pixels on picture from top left to right bottom and running flood fill on it to get all the pixels and storing that data on separate bitmaps. i am doing it for black and white bitmaps.

some how it works and gives me array of bitmaps for each found area/objects but problem is speed - which is very very slow. for that reason this method can not be used.

So if any one have a better solution to do so, kindly help me to achieve that goal.

Comment: If you want them separate you should draw them on separate canvas objects and have a "main" canvas objects for putting them together.

Comment: Emil, its not about drawing actually, its about bitmap tracing... but i don't want vectors i need bitmaps instead.